# Check if all divs are hidden

Tags: jquery

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/JrAhR/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".chk").click(function() {
        $(".chk:checked").each(function() {
           $("."+this.id).show();
        });       
        $(".chk:not(:checked)").each(function() {
           $("."+this.id).hide();
        }); 
        // give a message if nothing left to show       
    });  
});
```

```
<label>
    <input class="chk" type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="course">Courses
</label> 
<label>
    <input class="chk" type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="morning">Morning
</label> 
<label>
    <input class="chk" type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="evening">Evening
</label> 
<ul>
    <li class="courseBox course">Course</li>
    <li class="courseBox course evening">Course, Evening</li>
    <li class="courseBox morning">Morning </li>
</ul>​
```

How do I most elegantly know if all the affected divs were hidden?

---

UPDATE: If you need to check after a fadeOut, you need to put the check in the callback:

```
$(".chk:not(:checked)").each(function() {
  $("."+this.id).fadeOut(function() {
    if (!$('.courseBox:visible').length) {
      alert('all are hidden');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Don't you trust .show() and .hide()?

Comment: @j08691: It's clearer in the jsFiddle. Each checkbox hides certain elements. Because of overlapping classes, all the elements could be hidden before all checkboxes are unchecked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (!$('.courseBox:visible').length)
    alert('all are hidden');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JrAhR/6/

Answer (score 3):

Count the visible li elements:

```
 if ($('ul li:visible').length == 0) {
  alert("Everything is gone!")
 }
```

More info:

[:visible selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

Answer (score 2):

You need the `:visible` selector:

```
if ($('div:visible').length == 0) alert('no more divs!');
```

Comment: Gotta change "div" to "li"... @mplugjan is using list elements... but, this does work, too

Comment: Oh. I was just going off his question: "How do I most elegantly know if all the affected divs were hidden?". Didn't need to look at a jsfiddle for something this simple.

Comment: Right on... Yeah... it threw me, too... I messed with the jsFiddle and it wasn't working... lol

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$('ul').find(':hidden').length
```

This will give you the number of elements under "ul" that are hidden

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be simplified as below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".chk").click(function() {
        $("." + this.id).toggle(this.checked);
        if($(".courseBox:visible").length == 0){
            alert("All divs are hidden");
        }
    });        
});
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/JrAhR/13/

Comment: @mplungjan - Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: can you check your code? It looks like it works initially but after unchecking and checking, the intersection no longer works. My initial code handles intersection correctly

Comment: Your code also behaves like that after check and uncheck. What is your expected behavior? I will modify my code accordingly.

Comment: Your code allows an evening course even when course is unchecked. Mine works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/JrAhR/

Comment: It doesn't take a look again. When you uncheck `Course` it hides `Evening` too.

Comment: Yes it does. Uncheck all and then check evening.